# Making link in empty cells of HTML tables

Tags: php, html

I have a table. Is there any way to make link in only empty `td` (click on plus sign)

If any `td` has *name* or *age*, then skip making link

I hope anyone understand

index.php

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $name ;?><a href ="add.php">+</td>
<td><?php echo $age ;?><a href ="add.php">+</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: check if $name and $age are not blank, if blank make a variable with a value +, if not blank make a variable with anchor tag on +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+Try this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><?php echo (strlen(trim($name)) > 0) ? $name : "<a>+</a> ;?>+</td>
 <td><?php echo (strlen(trim($age)) > 0) ? $age : "<a>+</a> ;?>+</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: if `isset()` is there then why `strlen()`?

Comment: suppose $name has only a space

Comment: that will be invalid actually. also `isset()` will count that

Comment: By using isset, if $name has a space then it will not show the link.

Comment: that's why i said its an invalid thing to just put space in feilds

Comment: And Anant, there is a lot of ways to do the code for a same purpose. I used strlen, you used isset. So what is the issue man?? Tell me why you have used if condition when you can use ternary operator??

Comment: No one is putting the space in the variable. It may be coming from a textbox (user is entering a space)

Comment: I am not telling that you are wrong buddy.

Comment: As a developer you have to take care of all possible scenarios. So i think its good to check whether the variable is having only space.  Thanks Anant..!!  :)

Comment: vote for long discussion about empty space.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to check your value either set and not empty, if values are set than print value else print anchar link as:

**Example:**

```
<td>
    <?=(isset($name) && !empty($name) ? $name : "<a href ='add.php'>+</a>");?>
</td>
<td>
    <?=(isset($age) && !empty($age) ? $age : "<a href ='add.php'>+</a>");?>
</td>
```